# Can not get my laptop out of sleep mode ubuntu 20.04 on hp victus 16

Tags: suspend, 22.04, hp

I got my brand new Victus HP Gaming Laptop 16 when I installed ubuntu instead of windows the laptop did not get out of sleep mode even if I move the mouse or press the keyboard.

Comment: pm-suspend ( pm-utils) , systemcl suspend

Comment: have the same model and same issue